# Ember mirage server is not defined in tests

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

I am trying to integrate ember-cli-mirage fixtures into some tests. I followed the documentation here: [ember fixtures](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.x/fixtures/)

Problem: The server is not defined. error message:
`ReferenceError: server is not defined`

model-test.js:

```
import { moduleForModel, test } from 'ember-qunit';

moduleForModel('network', 'Unit | Model | network', {
  needs: []
});

test('it exists', function(assert) {
  server.loadFixtures('networks'); //no defined

andThen(function() {
   let net1 = networks.first();
});
  assert.ok(true);
});
```

I have also verified that the config is set to true.

```
ENV['ember-cli-mirage'] = {
        enabled: true
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mirage starts up in an initializer. Since initializers only run when a full Ember app boots up, by default the Mirage server is only available in an acceptance test.

To use Mirage in an integration or unit test, follow [the docs on manually starting your Mirage server](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.x/manually-starting-mirage/). Currently the docs say this:

> To run your Mirage server during a unit or integration test, first create a helper:
>
> ```
> // tests/helpers/start-mirage.js
> import mirageInitializer from '../../initializers/ember-cli-mirage';
>
> export default function startMirage(container) {
>    mirageInitializer.initialize(container);
>  }
> ```
>
> Then, add the following to any test where you want Mirage to initialize:
>
> ```
> // tests/integration/components/your-test.js
>  import startMirage from '../../../helpers/start-mirage';
>
> moduleForComponent('your-component', 'Integration | Component | your component', {
>    integration: true,
>    setup: function() {
>      startMirage(this.container);
>    }
>  });
> ```